# install npm package dependency via nexus

Tags: npm, dependencies, installation, nexus

So here is the problem

I installed systemjs from the online npm repo to a new empty project which was fine. I then republished this to an internal nexus repository which appeared to work.

However when I tried to install the systemjs repository from our nexus directory, the 'when.js' package was installed within the same node_module level as the systemjs package i.e. myproject->node_modules->when ? Not within myproject->node_modules->systemjs->node_modules->when ?

Can you tell me what I need to do to ensure that the systemjs dependancies are installed within myproject->node_modules->systemjs->node_modules->XXX and NOT myproject->node_modules->XXX ?

Answer (score 0):

Since npm v3 the dependency tree is kept as flat as possible to avoid duplication and overly deep directory structures. That results in placing the dependencies at the same level as the module that required them, unless there already exists another version of the dependency in which case it is installed nested. See the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3) for details.

In most cases you shouldn't have to worry about the structure of your `node_modules` directory. If you absolutely *need* to have all the dependencies nested, the only way currently seems to be [downgrading npm to v2](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9809).